# C: Dynamically Allocated Struct Array Usage

Tags: c, arrays, linux, dynamic, struct

Getting errors such as 
`stats.c:28:36: error: ‘factoryStats’ has no member named ‘candyConsumed’ factoryStatsArray[producer_number].candyConsumed++;`
What I want to be able to achieve is to create an array of structs, then access it's members. Is this the wrong way to do it?

Tried using `->` but that shouldn't and don't work since I'm storing structs, not pointers to structs.

```
#include "stats.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int factoryNumber = 0;
    int candyProduced = 0;
    int candyConsumed = 0;
    double minDelay = 0;
    double avgDelay = 0;
    double maxDelay = 0;
} factoryStats;

factoryStats *factoryStatsArray;
int NUM_FACTORIES = 0;

void stats_init (int num_producers) {
    factoryStatsArray = malloc(sizeof(factoryStats) * num_producers);
    NUM_FACTORIES = num_producers;
}
void stats_cleanup (void) {
    free(factoryStatsArray);
}
void stats_record_produced (int factory_number) {
    factoryStatsArray[factory_number].candyProduced++;
}
void stats_record_consumed (int producer_number, double delay_in_ms) {
    factoryStatsArray[producer_number].candyConsumed++;
    if (factoryStatsArray[producer_number].minDelay == 0) {
        factoryStatsArray[producer_number].minDelay = delay_in_ms;
    } else {
        if (factoryStatsArray[producer_number].minDelay > delay_in_ms) {
            factoryStatsArray[producer_number].minDelay = delay_in_ms;
        }
    }
    if (factoryStatsArray[producer_number].maxDelay == 0) {
        factoryStatsArray[producer_number].maxDelay = delay_in_ms;
    } else {
        if (factoryStatsArray[producer_number].maxDelay < delay_in_ms) {
            factoryStatsArray[producer_number].maxDelay = delay_in_ms;
        }
    }
    factoryStatsArray[producer_number].avgDelay+= delay_in_ms;

}
void stats_display(void) {
    printf("%8s%10s%10s10s10s10s\n", "Factory#", "#Made", "#Eaten", "Min Delay[ms]", "Avg Delay[ms]", "Max Delay[ms]");
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_FACTORIES; i++) {
            printf("%8d%8d%8d%10.5f%10.5f%10.5f",
                    factoryStatsArray[i].factoryNumber, factoryStatsArray[i].candyProduced,
                    factoryStatsArray[i].candyConsumed, factoryStatsArray[i].minDelay,
                    factoryStatsArray[i].avgDelay/factoryStatsArray[i].candyConsumed,
                    factoryStatsArray[i].maxDelay);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

structs cannot be initialized this way. Remove all those `= 0` in `typedef struct { ... } factoryStats;`. Afterwards it compiles as in http://ideone.com/uMgDzE .

Comment: @Aaron And just to add to this. If you want the struct data to be initialised to zero you'll need to memset to 0 after the malloc. Alternatively you can replace the malloc with calloc which does zero out the allocated memory: calloc(num_producers, sizeof(factoryStats)). Also, you have a potential memory leak - if stats_init gets called more than once. You need to check whether factoryStatsArray is NULL or not. If not NULL need to free it before malloc/calloc.